# OID comparison in IBM DB2

Tags: db2, compare, sqldatatypes, oid, object-relational-model

I'm trying to use object oriented features of DB2 for the first time. I've created types, typed tables and inserted data. The problem is I can't compare user generated OIDs.

My type:

```
CREATE TYPE "orschema"."pojistovna_typ" AS(
nazev VARCHAR(30), 
cislo VARCHAR(3))
INSTANTIABLE
REF USING INTEGER
MODE DB2SQL;
```

My typed table:

```
CREATE TABLE "orschema"."pojistovna" OF "orschema"."pojistovna_typ"
(REF IS oid USER GENERATED);
```

Succesfully inserted data with command:

```
INSERT INTO "orschema"."pojistovna" (oid, nazev, cislo)
  VALUES("orschema"."pojistovna_typ"(1), 'ccc', '105');
```

But this SELECT doesn't work at all, but in IBM knowledge is it done the same way:

```
SELECT * FROM "orschema"."pojistovna" AS "p"
WHERE "p"."oid" = "orschema"."pojistovna_typ"(1);
```

ERROR: data types are not compatible or not comparable with "="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is using CAST funcion, but I'm not sure if this won't slow down this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "orschema"."pojistovna" AS "p" WHERE CAST("p".oid AS INTEGER) = 1;
```